# What is wrong with my python code on Wallis product?

Tags: python

So, I was asked to code the Wallis product and it wasn't supposed to be really complicated. So I made a code but apparently, it could only work for `Wallis(1)` and not the rest. Could anyone help me? Thank you!

```
def Wallis (n):
    result = 1
    for count in range(2, n+2, 2):
        result = result * (count**2/((count-1)*(count+1)))
    return result
```

Formula to compute Wallis product

```
(2*2)/(3*5) * (4*4)/(5*7) * (6*6)/(7*9) and so on until ((n*2) ** 2)/ ((n-1)* (n+1))
```

Output

```
Wallis(1) = (2*2)/(3*5) = 0.267
Wallis(2) = Wallis(1) * (4*4)/(5*7) = 0.122
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really know. The formula given is (2*2)/(3*5) * (4*4)/(5*7) * (6*6)/(7*9) and so on until ((n*2) ** 2)/ ((n-1)* (n+1))

Comment: I'm kinda new to this website sorry

Comment: Shouldn't that be `range(2, 2*n+2, 2)`. BTW, `count*count` is faster than `count**2`. FWIW, I get `2*Wallis(1000000) == 3.141591868192167`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said, your `range()` needs to be changed.

For n=3,

```
for count in range(2, n+2, 2):
    print(i)
```

would print

```
2
4
```

but you needed `6` as well.

As Python documentation says

```
class range(start, stop[, step])
```

> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.

meaning `stop` is not included.

Here `step` is `2`, you could use

```
for count in range(2, 2*(n+1), 2):
```

And exponentiation is costlier than multiplication. So

```
count*count
```

is better than

```
count**2
```

So the modified version could be

```
def Wallis(n):
    result=1
    for count in range(2, 2*(n+1), 2):
        result*=((count*count)/((count-1)*(count+1)))
    return result
```

Note that the value returned by `Wallis` is only half the value of Pi.

You could modify the `return` statement to

```
return result*2
```

if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly your range command is wrong:

```
range(2, 2*n+2, 2)
```

Alternatively, you can move the complexity to the formula, i.e.:

```
for count in range(1, n):
    result = result * (4*count*count/((2*count-1)*(2*count+1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `count` is equal to `2*n` in your equation so in `(count**2/((count-1)*(count+1)))`, `count**2` is the same as `(2*n)**2` however the following `count-1` should be the same as `n-1` but rather it is actually `(2*n)-1`. The same goes for `count+1`.

I made my own version which should help you (although I used a different equation which is at https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Wallis_product)

```
def wallis(limit):
    result = 1
    for x in range(2, limit, 2):
        result *= (x / (x - 1)) * (x / (x + 1))
    return result
```

As `limit` gets higher, it converges closer to half pi.